# How to evaluate $s_\lambda(q,q^2,\cdots,q^m)$? (principal specialisation of the schur function)

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

It is required to show that

$$
s_\lambda(q,q^2,\cdots,q^m) = q^{m(\lambda)}\prod_{i,j \in \lambda}\frac{1-q^{c_{i,j}+m}}{1-q^{h_{i,j}}}
$$

where $c_{i,j}=j-i$ is the content of cell $(i,j)$, and $h_{i,j}$ is the hook length, $m(\lambda) = \sum_i i\lambda_i$, and $s_\lambda$ is the Schur function.

Seriously I spent several days and found no proof on the internet at all. People say this is Stanley's formula, and I found the original paper (*Theory and Application of Plane Partitions.
Part 2*), and there is no clue. (Symbols in that paper are vastly different from what we use today, but if I'm right he only did the case when $q=1$).

What I thought was (correct me at any chance), since $s_\lambda(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)$ is the generating function of all semistandard $\lambda$-tableaux with non-negative entries of size less than $m$. If we replace $x_i$ with $q^i$, then I can combine all terms accordingly. I was thinking about a way to 'scan' the tableaux cell-by-cell, which may envolve hook length and content. But I didn't know how to start.

Comment: see https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/107965/26_2016_Article_312.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y.

Comment: and also R. P. Stanley (Enum. Comb. Vol. 2 (1999) pg 375 Theorem 7.21.2